# Cannot find namespace error for model in Angular2/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

#### The FeaturedCategories model

```
export class FeaturedCategories {
    categories: Array<{ id: number, title: string, graphic: string, categorycards: Array<{}> }>;
}
```

Also tried this:

```
export class FeaturedCategories {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    graphic: string;
    categorycards: Object[];
}
```

#### The Component

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../shared/services/api.service';
import { FeaturedCategories } from '../shared/models/home/featuredcategories';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
    selector: 'home',
    styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    testFeaturedCategories: Array<FeaturedCategories>;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {
        // we need the data synchronously for the client to set the server response
        // we create another method so we have more control for testing
        this.universalInit();
    }

    universalInit() {
        console.log('universalInit...')
        this.api.getFeatured()
            .subscribe(categories => {
                console.log('categories', categories);
                this.testFeaturedCategories = categories
            });
    }
}
```

---

This will work: `testFeaturedCategories: Array<{}>;`

However I'm trying to use TypeScript to let my App know what type of model to expect.

This causes the error above:
`testFeaturedCategories: FeaturedCategories.categories;`

And if I just try this: `testFeaturedCategories: FeaturedCategories;`

I get a `type [{}] is not assignable` error.

[image]

[image]

---

#### UPDATE

So I noticed that when I commented out all the keys in my `FeaturedCategories` model finally the error goes away and

`featuredCategories: FeaturedCategories[];` will work.

However now this is just an empty object without keys to expect :(

```
export class FeaturedCategories {
    // id: number;
    // title: string;
    // graphic: string;
    // categorycards: Object[];
}
```

Comment: `It says it's undefined:` <= well yeah, you broke on the line before you set a value. Also do not call service code chained from the constructor. Use ngInit for that.

Comment: I'm using Angular-universal to serve up static pages with Node. I assumed the `universalInit` replaces `ngInit`? Also featureCategories is typed to FeaturedCategories my model, so it should have something by now. I'm trying to re-create this in a plnkr atm.

Comment: You call it from the constructor, that is wrong. Call it  from ngInit or there might be an interface you need to implement that defines universalInit. Eitherway do not call it from the constructor.

Comment: Also I can't find any method named `universalInit` or interface that defines such a method in the repo.

Comment: Ok I re-created a plnkr here that is close: https://plnkr.co/edit/gwa3NWArtWK0wjf2jr2h?p=preview I can't see any Typescript errors in plnkr, but I put in 2 console.logs

Comment: Sorry but I am not going to look or help troubleshoot a plunk using an Alpha version of Angular. Angular has been out a while now and the latest version is 2.4.9 (*as of today*), please use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was trying to type my Array, instead of just using the Typed objects that exist in the larger Array.

Also had a problem in my service, originally I had this:

```
/**
 * Get featured categories data for homepage
 * /wiki
 */
getFeatured(): Observable<[{}]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.getFeaturedUrl}/home`)
    // .do(res => console.log('getFeatured res', res.json()))
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I did not need or could even use a type for my larger Categories array, what I needed was a smaller type for the exact Objects that exist in that larger Array:

```
export class FeaturedCategory {
    id?: number;
    type: string;
    title: string;
    graphic?: string;
    video?: string;
    categorycards: Array<{}>;
}
```

So now with the correct Type of Objects inside my Array I added it to the service:

```
getFeatured(): Observable<[FeaturedCategory]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.getFeaturedUrl}/home`)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

[image]

Now back in my Component I imported the single Typed Object

```
import { FeaturedCategory } from '../shared/models/home/featuredcategory';
```

Then typed the variable:

```
featuredCategories: Array<FeaturedCategory>;
```

And finally in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getFeatured()
        .subscribe(categories => {
            console.log('categories', categories);
            this.featuredCategories = categories;
        });
}
```

No more errors :)

Answer (score 1):

this is working fine for me.

```
export class MyComponent {
 categories: FeaturedCategories[] = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "",
  graphic: "",
  categorycards: [{}]
 }];
}

export class FeaturedCategories{
 id: number;
 title: string;
 graphic: string;
 categorycards: Object[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting the same error `type [{}] is not assignable to type FeaturedCategories`

Comment: Can you console the response and add to question ? Probably you are receiving empty object in response as error says it only have assignment issue.

Comment: Added! This is when using the model design you wrote.

Comment: Weird! those objects have all these properties `{ id: number, title: string, graphic: string, categorycards: Array<{}> }` ? let me check locally as well with same model

Comment: Still the same problem :( I'll have to see if I can mini-mize my app and remake it in Plnkr and will add the link here. Another thing tho, `FeaturedCategories` is suppose to return an Array, not an Object. That's why originally I had another key in there `categories`. Possible issue there?

Comment: Create a plunkr snippet we'll see the problem over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137486/discussion-between-leon-gaban-and-babar-bilal).

Comment: Here is my plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gwa3NWArtWK0wjf2jr2h?p=preview I can't see any Typescript errors obviously, but this shows what I'm trying to do. Perhaps more simply, how should the `FeaturedCategories` class export be written to match: `Array<{}>` because that's the only thing that works in my component.

Comment: I just figured it out, I had a large modal and a smaller modal for the object, also my api.service was typed wrong. Will explain in my answer.

Comment: Btw +1 for all the time you took to help me out.